# Dell R720 and Ubuntu display issues

Tags: ubuntu, dell, gnome, nvidia, grid

Dell R720
Matrox G200 Embedded Graphics
2x Nvidia GRID K1
Ubuntu Server 19.10

After pure install, display is 640x480, but after installing nvidia-340 drivers, gdm does not start. K1 GPUs don't have any output ports. GPUs are attached via PCI. Primary display is connected to default R720 back-panel VGA connector.

Already tried to manually change driver in xorg.conf, but with no success. Still cannot run Gnome DE.

Command nvidia-smi shows all cores and params of installed 2xNvidia GRID K1.

**Need help to run Gnome on primary display.**

**Update**
I didn't solve the problem, even install Ubuntu Desktop, Nvidia-CUDA-toolkit, or playing with GRUB for customized boot. Currently I run almost the same application, except now there is double Nvidia GTX installed. And it works fine.

Comment: You need to remove the NVIDIA drivers and install the MGA drivers. However, you will still have problems and will need to make further changes https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035

Comment: But if I remove them I will not be able to use Nvidia GPUs. That's not a solution. Or maybe You mean sth else...

Comment: Why do you need a monitor on a rack server in the first place? Just install a headless server or run a  vncserver if you really need a gui. AFAIK you don't need a GUI install to use CUDA.

Comment: Server runs a program that needs to be executed in GUI and have OpenGL support and access to Nvidia hardware. Can't obviously use headless. Tried also MGA driver, but with no luck.